# Given 2 positive integer x, y has 10^5 digits in hexadecimal. What is the sum of digits of product of all integer in range [x, y]?

Tags: algorithm

Given 2 positive integer x, y has 10<sup>5</sup> digits in hexadecimal (x, y could be FFF....F (10<sup>5</sup> in length)). Do changes:

1. Calculate the product of all integer that in range [x, y].
2. Calculate the sum until the result has only 1 digit.
3. Print that digit.

For example:

1. All integer in range [x, y] = {1BA, 1BB, 1BC, 1BD} (in Decimal is {442, 443, 444, 445})
2. The product of all integer is 1BA x 1BB x 1BC x 1BD = 901F21AE8 (in Decimal is 38687349480)
3. Sum the digit until the result has only 1 digit:

   - 901F21AE8 → 9 + 0 + 1 + F + 2 + 1 + A + E + 8 = 3C
   - 3C → 3 + C = F
4. Print "F"

I tried the bruteforce way (do exactly what it said) but I got time limit exceeded. Is there any better algorithm?

Comment: In your example, you get the same result if you sum the coefficients of each element (reitering until result is less than 15) before the multiplication. Proving it in a rigorous way seems tricky

Comment: "10^5 digits in hexadecimal" can you clarify it little bit. What is the maximum possible of x or y? does it 100000 in hex or 186A0 (which is equivalent to 100000 in decimal) or something else.

Comment: @ManojBanik I my understanding, it mean numbers up to `16^{10^5} - 1`

Comment: @Damien, so x and y could be as large as FFF....F (10^5 in length)?

Comment: @ManojBanik It is what I understand. It is why a drastic simplification is requested, as the one I proposed in my first comment. No totally sure it works. At least it works in the example provided in the question. Obtained product is 7x8x9x10=5040=H13B0 -> F (sorry for mistake in previous comment)

Comment: After a few trial calculations, it looks like the answer is always "F" except in trivial cases where x and y are both less than 6. It's worth noting that the product of all the numbers from x to y is equal to y! / (x-1)!, and every factorial greater than 4! has a digital root of 15 in base 16.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Sorry, I miss something. If you mutiply 11E and 11F, you get 82822 = H140A2 -> sum = 17 = H11 -> sum = 2. Besides, Sum(11E) = 1 and Sum(11F) = 2

Comment: @Damien (correction) Ah, you're right. This only seems to happen when y=x+1. I  think perhaps the digital root of x*y gives the correct answer in these cases. But I have no idea why!

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up your calculations by the "Divide and Conquer" algorithm using multithreading. Divide your numbers into blocks and recursively multiply all the numbers in each block together.

Comment: Could you clarify it? "Divide your numbers into blocks": which number i have to divide?

Comment: For an example, you have an array: [x, y] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}. To calculate a product of this numbers you can multiply them step by step: 1. 1 x 2 = 2; 2. 2 x 3 = 6; 3. 6 x 4 = 24;  and so on. Or you ca divide your numbers into blocks: {1, 2, 3} and {4, 5, 6}. Then make calculation for first block: 1 x 2 x 3 = 6. And for second block: 4 x 5 x 6 = 120; And get a result: 6 x 120 = 720. You can create several blocks. And create subblocks.
A main goal of this operations is launch calculations in parallel by several threads.